# What exactly are "history" and "retries" meant to mean in Allure?

Tags: testing, protractor, report, history, allure

I'm new to Allure. Thus, not everything is too clear to me yet. The documentation, examples and explanations on https://allurereport.org/ don't help me understand my question any better:

What are "History" and "Retries" meant to represent?

---

### How I imagine it to be:

Say, I have several testcases of the same testsuite.

```
1) [Testcase_2017-11-27_15-10-05] 
2) [Testcase_2017-11-27_15-30-13]
3) [Testcase_2017-11-27_15-43-09]
```

If I clicked on 1), it should have:

```
History: empty
Retries: 2), 3)
```

If I clicked on 2), it should have:

```
History: 1)
Retries: 3)
```

If I clicked on 3), it should have:

```
History: 1), 2)
Retries: empty
```

---

Is it even possible to get this done this way?
Are "History" and "Retries" meant to be understood this way?

I'd be thankful for any helpful comments!

---

*I am using: protractor, jasmine-allure-reporter, allure-commandline*

Answer (score 2):

History is supposed to show you the execution history of the same test cases (test case signature is calculated based on test method name and parameters) across multiple test suite executions. See https://allurereport.org/docs/gettingstarted-history/ for details.

Retires are executions of the same test cases (a signature is calculated based on the test method name and parameters as well) within one test suite execution, e.g. when we are using TestNG IRetryAnalyzer or JUnit retry Rules. I'm not sure if there is something similar for Jasmine.

History is normally supported out-of-the-box by CI Allure Plugins. See https://allurereport.org/docs/how-it-works-history-files/

Comment: thanks!
I was really confused, because I didn't see any history being created.
Found a fix though:
https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/682#issuecomment-348225831